# What is this hashed Session Name when I run qwinsta on my Win10 workstation?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, session, terminal-services

Question is title, I can't find any information about what this session is. I googled `7a78855482a04` and got some random results mostly from a couple people that were wondering the same thing. I don't use remote management software or tools.

[image: Qwinsta Console]

Any ideas?

Thanks so much for any information.

Comment: Win10 Enterprise 21H1 here, `qwinsta` shows: `SESSIONNAME=rdp-tcp ; ID=65536 ; STATE=Listen; every other field is blank` & RDP is enabled on my PC. `tasklist /fi "session eq 65536"` didn't provide anything, no processes open under that session, but command does work. I am just pointing out what may be normal (although undesired/misunderstood by @Jay)

Comment: Could also be related to _Remote Assistance_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I HIGHLY suspect its [Windows Remote Desktop listening for a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453993/1575219) as @harrymc pointed out. I can't explain why its hashed/worded-funny, however it IS odd its there if you have disabled Remote Desktop as [you mentioned in a comment to harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1686111/160219). However to confirm any suspicions run this command `net stop termservice`, after it's down my RDP 'Listen' session disappeared & I suspect your hashed one will as well. That'll make you feel better it's not malicious. I agree it SHOULDN'T be listening if you disabled it. Below is an article that can show you a bunch of things to check to confirm you really HAVE disabled it on the backend:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/troubleshoot/rdp-error-general-troubleshooting

Comment: I ended up doing `net stop termservice` and that stopped the "Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector" but it hung on stopping Remote Desktop Services. So I ran `sc queryex TermService` and got the PID (1488) and then did `taskkill /pid 1488 /f` 

After all that I ran qwinsta and the hashed value was gone.

Additionally I disabled RDP in ('Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections > Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services.') to disabled.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Might also hung on stopping, oh Windows! If you're willing you should upvote harrymc's answer as I believe it helped both of us

Answer (score 2):

The session with the hash-like name is in the "Listen" state.

The Microsoft article
[WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-wts_connectstate_class)
specifies the connection state of a Remote Desktop Services session,
where is found this value:

> **WTSListen**
>
> The WinStation is listening for a connection. A listener session waits
> for requests for new client connections. No user is logged on a
> listener session. A listener session cannot be reset, shadowed, or
> changed to a regular client session.

It seems to me that what you see is an unconnected session, waiting
and available for a connection by any user.

I can't see such a session when I fire up a Windows Server VM,
so a further guess would be that perhaps this WinStation is a
left-over from some user disconnecting from his session, but
that's only a guess.

Comment: That's concerning since I don't use any kind of remoting tools, nor do I use remote desktop. I am going to wait for additional answers that will hopefully provide some more clarity. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your Windows version?

Comment: Win10 Pro, Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1288)

Comment: Is RDP enabled in *Settings > System > Remote Desktop*?

Comment: Nope, it's disabled.

Comment: Try the command `tasklist /fi "session eq 65536"` which hopefully will find which processes are running in this session. Run CMD as Administrator just in case.

Comment: "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria."

Comment: I see that Greg has finally verified my answer, before I could go on with suggesting the check that he did.