# I'm not understanding Query Session command

Tags: windows, command-line

When I type `query session` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to display a list of active sessions.
The output displays session id starting with `655` and in a state `Listen` - how do I track what this is?

When I use the command `query process /session: [session_id]` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, replacing `[session_id]` with the session ID I want to investigate, it returns `invalid session id`. Just curious what this session in listening state could be? Has anyone seen this before?

Also I have two one with a random session name starting with 31c5 and a session id 65536 which is in a listen state and the other is Rdp-tcp on 65537

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Query ID doesn't help us identify what it is, provide `sessionname` and other displayed info instead. But in general, Process Monitor can be helpful to identify which processes are using that session if you filter by that ID.

Answer (score 0):

The session ID `655` or `65536` in the `Listen` state is typically reserved for the RDP-Tcp listener session, which listens for incoming Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) connections. This session is created by the operating system when the Remote Desktop Services role is enabled, and it is not an actual user session. Instead, it is a system session that is always present when the Remote Desktop Services role is enabled on a Windows Server.

Since it is not an actual user session, you cannot query its processes using the `query process /session:[session_id]` command, and it will return an "invalid session id" error message.

So, you don't need to worry about this session ID, as it's a standard part of the Windows Server operating system when Remote Desktop Services are enabled.

Comment: I have two one with a random session name starting with 31c5 and a session id  65536 which is in a listen state and the other is 
Rdp-tcp on 65537

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the same (also a hashed listen session starting with 31c5c...) on my Win10 22H2 Clients (>100 Clients).
Closest I got to uncovering what this is was:

[What is this hashed Session Name when I run qwinsta on my Win10 workstation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1685510/what-is-this-hashed-session-name-when-i-run-qwinsta-on-my-win10-workstation)

If I run the commands as suggested in the answer:

```
net stop termservice

sc queryex TermService

taskkill /pid [PID output from command above] /f
```

the hashed session disappears. So I guess it really is just Windows being Windows ^__^